# Should the app bar overlap the content?

Tags: android, mobile-application

Due to the requirements, the second app bar line contains additional information which is shown by expanding it just about the expansion panels.

Regarding the material properties the app bar is higher on the z-axis, so it could overlap the content (which would be also okay).

On the other hand when you scroll up the app bar could fade out upward, so the content affects the app bar to move with the content. Seen on this regard, the content could also move downward when expanding the app bar.

Just one of both can be implemented. I would appreciate other opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule to remember here is the priorities. Content comes first and than the interface. The content must be accessible, visible, readable and understandable. Let's assume you have these boxes ticked.

Now let's this on how the implementation of above may affect the content. Will is stop people from reading it? Will it cover the content? Will it make content less accessible? If any of these will un-tick any of our boxes, such feature should not be implemented.

The next task is to compare two possible scenarios.

1. Show over content

User clicks the bar -> Additional content appears over the content -> User performs an action -> Additional content disappears.

2. Move content to show

User clicks the bar -> Additional content slides out and moves the content away -> **User loses the view of the content** -> User performs action -> Additional content slides up -> Content reappears

Bearing this in mind, I would suggest to avoid moving content away of users view.

You can perform deeper analysis taking in consideration all of this: [Checklist of Checkpoints for Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10/full-checklist.html)

Answer (score 1):

Google actually explains their elevation principles pretty well here:
[Elevation and shadows](https://material.google.com/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#).

This image demonstrates what's beneath and what's above the app bar.
[image]